# Serial connection crossover

Tags: putty, serial-port

When accessing a serial connection I only get random numbers and characters: [http://i.imgur.com/NsGIamE.png](https://i.imgur.com/NsGIamE.png)
The manual for the piece of hardware I am trying to access says following about the connection:

Connect serial port to a PC through null modem cable (RXD / TXD crossed over). Set terminal emulator to 115200 8N1.

The adapter I am using is from Logilink using the Prolific drivers and for the connection I am using putty. The correct speed and bits/parity are set and I turned flow control off.

Do the numbers mean I got a straight cable instead of a crossover one or is something else wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264386/usb-serial-communication-giving-strange-output/29270320#29270320

Comment: A straight-thru serial cable wouldn't connect at all, you have a cross-over (aka "null modem") cable.  I'd guess it's most likely a crappy serial port adapter.  But how/where exactly did you configure the port settings?  Can you provide a screenshot of the settings?

Comment: Certainly. http://i.imgur.com/wEfcbtZ.png http://i.imgur.com/aCgMzXS.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out at that the cable was somehow faulty. Using RealTerm I was able to determine that the signal was not stable. Fixed the cable and now the console displays properly.